# Durandal canDeactive lifecycle callback

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I currently have my canDeactive callback being called twice when I return false.

The call stacks are identical with the only difference being that in system.js the acquire function args variable has differing values on each call.

The first time my breakpoint in the nested setTimeout is hit the args have a value of my navigating to view.

The second time round (split second) the args value is of my current view that I have stated may not deactivate.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Am I perhaps doing something wrong with my require statements in each view

*Edit More Info*

My setup: (- denotes nesting)

Shell

-header

-view1

--nested view (bound using knockout)

-view2

-view3

--nested view

In order to  navigate between views I have a property on each view that states it's page heading and also any link items, so for example view1 header: "Page 1", links [{path: "#/view2"}]. Each one of my views 'requires' the header view, and sets these options on activate (I dislike this piece as it feels like a hack but that's for another day).

When clicking a link I call a function on the shell which in turn calls router.navigateTo(*path of item clicked*) or back on view3.

I can confirm this issue occurs across all views (1,2 and 3), and also canActivate along with the other lifecycle callbacks fire once as expected and in the correct order.

Sorry for the lack of code but I'm not sure where to look as it seems to be something that controls the requireing on navigation (due to the single difference found mentioned above)

Comment: Really need to see some code to help.  canDeactivate should only be called as you are trying to leave the view, my best guess would be you have a function that is trying to leave and then you are calling that function again inside of your canDeactivate method.

Comment: sadly it isn't to do with the content of the canDeactivate callback as I have proved the behavior with: 

canDeactivate: function (isClose) {
            return false;
        }

See my edits above for more info on my current solution.

Comment: Please post your canDeactivate method as well as wherever you are saying canDeactivate in your view if that is indeed what you are doing.  canDeactivate is not meant to be in your view, as it is not a computed observable if that is what you are doing.  canDeactivate is called by the router when it is trying to leave.

Comment: Your canDeactivate method is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue, the problem child was my default.html, having moved my script imports to below my applicationhost (a la a durandal demo piece) my canDeactivate no longer fires twice upon receiving a false return.